# Counting white clusters horizontally in a processed fabric

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I processed a fabric material to obtain the image as shown below:

Original image:

[image]

Processed Image:

[image]

Now, I want to find the number white clusters in a row. If all the clusters are uniform and perfectly horizontal, I would have run a loop to count the raise and drop in intensities to find number of clusters ,but thats not the case.If I take median/mean of several rows by the above method, the required answer is differing by a huge margin.

Is there any way to count them accurately on the constraint that rows need not be perfectly horizontal?Or Would following any method makes the task simpler?

Answer (score 2):

I am still thinking about this further, but for the moment, it seems **ImageMagick** does a pretty good job of deskewing your image. Just in Terminal (or Command Prompt on Windows):

```
 convert fabric.jpg -deskew 50% result.jpg
```

[image]

Here is an animation of what happens if you rotate your image from -20 to +20 degrees and on the right-hand side I show the projection (row sum) of each row. Watch that rightmost column as the left-hand side becomes horizontal:

[image]

Comment: Nice animation!

Comment: Could you provide the code for that projection and rotating the image? Is there any way/package to do such things in python?

Comment: It’s just `np.sum(grayimage, axis=1)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell , yes its np.sum only but how to get GIF with intensities beside the image

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can find out the number of connected components and get the number of labels as bellow. here  **bp8OO.jpg** your grayscale image. Now I guess you can do something on this for finding out how many in each row.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('bp8OO.jpg', 0)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  # ensure binary
ret, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(img)

print("Number of labels" , len(labels))

def show_components(labels):
    # Map component labels to hue val
    label_hue = np.uint8(179*labels/np.max(labels))
    blank_ch = 255*np.ones_like(label_hue)
    labeled_img = cv2.merge([label_hue, blank_ch, blank_ch])

    # cvt to BGR for display
    labeled_img = cv2.cvtColor(labeled_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

    # set bg label to black
    labeled_img[label_hue==0] = 0

    cv2.imshow('labeled.png', labeled_img)
    cv2.waitKey()

show_components(labels)
```

[image]